# Need a Solution to stop screen updating in CATIA

Tags: vba, catia

I was opening several parts in Catia and doing some stuff, I don't want to show that to the user. I want some empty screen to show the user or any other solution to bypass this

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

You can hide the catia application:

```vb
CATIA.Visible = False
```

disable the refreshing:

```
CATIA.RefreshDisplay = False
```

Try to use `.Read` instead of `.Open` a document